# Using elasticsearch to find similar vectors or long strings

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch

We are currently using a bag-of-features approach to indexing millions of images. The idea is to translate each image into a bag of feature tokens. There could be 100s of tokens in this bag. We map these feature tokens to unique integers, so each image ends up being translated into a string. Something like '1 3 5 45 ... 565 .. 9176'  These are all fixed length strings with 300 integers.  These integers range from 1 - 10000

We now want to use this string and retrieve other strings that are very similar. In this case similar would mean strings that have the most integers in common.

Our current index has about 50 million documents, where each of these documents is a fixed string described above. We are currently just doing dumb default tokenization while indexing. This results in us getting a search latency of about 5 to 6 seconds.  How can we do a better job and reduce this latency to under a second?

Answer (score 1):

> We now want to use this string and retrieve other strings that are
>   very similar. In this case similar would mean strings that have the
>   most integers in common.

There are probably many ways to do this, but one way would be to store the tokens in a bitmap (or bitset) instead of converting and storing them in a string.

For example: create a bitmap of 10000 bits and for each token set the corresponding bit. Then, to calculate the number of common tokens just do a logical AND on both bitsets and count the number of set bits in the result.

Those bitmaps could also be compressed in some form that would allow them to be read (in blocks of 32 or 64 bits) without decompressing first (10000 / 300 is 1 set bit every 33 bits on average, so a lot of blocks would be all zero).

Modern CPU's have a built-in popcount instruction to do a fast count of the set bits.

Also SSE or even AVX could be used to speed things up.

This data structure would also be ideal to process on a GPU, with hundreds or even thousands of cores (CUDA).

Not sure if this is possible with elasticsearch, but it could be done with some external code.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do a faster search, but this would mean setting up separate infrastructure, allowing for tens of requests every second. We'll resort to this if there's no easy way to just do this with our existing stack.